# Adding nodes and lines to a table

Tags: tikz-pgf, tables, macros, nodes

I am trying to draw a table like the one in the picture below. I've been working with tables and tikz but never combined both to draw a table with nodes in it.

[image: Desired Table]

What would be the best approach to draw such a table?

I created a minimum working example, which still has some issues.

- I don't know how to control the alignment of the lines inside the cells
- The circles are missing
- I did not include the horizontal and vertical lines as I also don't know how to align them.

Any help is appreciated. I can also use other packages if necessary. This was just my first idea.

Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array,multirow,graphicx}
 \usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark}
 \begin{document}
 \begin{table}[h]
 \centering
 \begin{tabular}{c|l|cccccc}
 Kategorie& \multicolumn{1}{c|}{Einflussgroesse} & \multicolumn{6}{c}{Auspraegung in Fallstudie} \\
 &&&1&2&3&4&\\
 \hline
 \multirow{4}{*}{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{\parbox[c]{1.5cm}{\centering Markt-bezogene }}} & text &gering&&\tikzmark{1}&&&hoch\\
 & text &gering&&\tikzmark{2}&&&hoch\\
 & text &gering&&&\tikzmark{3}&&hoch\\
  & text &gering&&&\tikzmark{4}&&hoch\\
 \end{tabular}
 \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay, remember picture]
    \draw [-] ({pic cs:1}) -- ({pic cs:2});
    \draw [-] ({pic cs:2}) -- ({pic cs:3});
    \draw [-] ({pic cs:3}) -- ({pic cs:4});
  \end{tikzpicture}
 \end{table}
 \end{document}
```

Which will give:
[image: Output]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you put the table inside a [tikz](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/pgf) `matrix of nodes` (see chapter 20 of the tikz/pgf manual), then you will have the full power of `tikz` at your disposal. To all intents and purposes a `matrix of nodes` looks like a "normal" LaTeX matrix except:

- It sits inside a `tikzpicture` environment.
- You can style the rows., columns, nodes ... in the usual tikz fashion
- It is straightforward to draw lines etc between the entries of the matrix.

Here the result of my experimenting with your MWE:

[image]

...and here is the code that produced this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,matrix}

\newcommand\hochscale[1]{%\hochscale{a,b,c,d,...}
  \foreach \r in {1,2,3,4} {% put numbers under heading
     \node at ($ (M-1-3.west)+(\r,-0.4) $) {\r};
  }
  % now draw scale in each row
  \foreach \hoch [count=\r from 2, remember=\r as \last] in {#1} {
    \node[anchor=west] at ($ (M-\r-3.west)+(-0.8,0) $) {gering};
    \node[anchor=east] at ($ (M-\r-3.west)+(5.5,0) $)    {hoch};
    \draw (M-\r-3.west)+(0.5,0) -- ++(4.5,0);
    \node[mypoint] (hoch\r) at ($ (M-\r-3.west)+(\hoch,0) $) {};
    \ifnum\r>2% draw the lines between scales starting from row 3
      \draw[blue](hoch\last)--(hoch\r);
    \fi
  }
  % add the dashed line
  \draw[dashed](M-2-3.west)+(2.5,0.5)--($ (M-\last-3.west)+(2.5,-0.5) $);
}

\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[mypoint/.style={circle, radius=0.5mm, fill=blue}]
    \matrix (M)[matrix of nodes, nodes in empty cells,
                row sep=8mm, column sep=6mm,
                row 1/.style = {anchor=center, font=\large\bfseries, blue,
                                minimum height=12mm},% to allow for numbers
                column 1/.style = {text width=15mm},
                column 2/.style = {text width=60mm},
                column 3/.style = {text width=60mm},
                ]{
     Kategorie & Einflussgroesse &  Auspraegung in Fallstudie\\
               & text 1 & \\
               & text 2 & \\
               & text 3 & \\
               & text 4 & \\
               & text 5 & \\
     };
     \draw[blue, thick](M-1-1.south west) -- (M-1-3.south east);
     \node[rotate=90, anchor=east] at (M-3-1) {Markt-bezogene};
     \hochscale{1,2,3,2,4}% add scales in column 3
  \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

A few comments:

- The `(M)` after the `\matrix` command says that the nodes of the matrix can be referred to as `(M-1-1)`, `(M-1-2)`, ... and more generally `(M-row-col)`, where `row` and `col` are any row and column indices. You can replace `M` with anything you like.
- The `\hochscale` command prints the scales in column 3. It accepts a comma separated list of the "scale values" after which it does the rest. This command is basically a `\foreach` statement running over the values. It uses the `(M-\r-3)` syntax to refer to the node in row `\r` and column 3. The node positions of the form `($ .... $)` use the tikz `calc` library.
- I have added some random styling to row 1. In general the styling is random and you should change to suit your needs. (In particular, there is currently too much blue!)
- In practice, you will probably need to change the width of the columns so that it better suits your text. In particular, you will probably need to shrink the scales in column 3 because otherwise I do not think that your text will fit.
- As explained in the [booktabs](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/booktabs) manual, it is usually better to avoid vertical lines in tables.
- A better example of the possibilities of styling is perhaps:

[image]

which is given by a few minor tweaks to the tikz style definitions:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,matrix}

\newcommand\hochscale[1]{%\hochscale{a,b,c,d,...}
  \foreach \r in {1,2,3,4} {
     \node at ($ (M-1-3.west)+(\r,-0.4) $) {\r};
  }
  \foreach \hoch [count=\r from 2, remember=\r as \last] in {#1} {
    \node[anchor=west] at ($ (M-\r-3.west)+(-0.8,0) $) {gering};
    \node[anchor=east] at ($ (M-\r-3.west)+(5.5,0) $)    {hoch};
    \draw (M-\r-3.west)+(0.5,0) -- ++(4.5,0);
    \node[mypoint] (hoch\r) at ($ (M-\r-3.west)+(\hoch,0) $) {};
    \ifnum\r>2%
      \draw[Peru](hoch\last)--(hoch\r);
    \fi
  }
  \draw[dashed](M-2-3.west)+(2.5,0.5)--($ (M-\last-3.west)+(2.5,-0.5) $);
}

\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[mypoint/.style={circle, radius=0.5mm, draw=Peru, thick, fill=Tan}]
    \matrix (M)[matrix of nodes, nodes in empty cells,
                row sep=2mm, column sep=8mm,
                row 1/.style = {anchor=center, font=\large\bfseries, Peru,
                                minimum height=12mm},% to allow for numbers
                column 1/.style = {text width=15mm},
                row 1 column 2/.style = {nodes={fill=white,draw=white},text width=50mm},
                column 2/.style = {nodes={rectangle,draw=Peru,fill=PapayaWhip},text width=50mm},
                column 3/.style = {text width=60mm},
                ]{
     Kategorie & Einflussgroesse &  Auspraegung in Fallstudie\\
               & text 1 & \\
               & text 2 & \\
               & text 3 & \\
               & text 4 & \\
               & text 5 & \\
     };
     \draw[Sienna, thick](M-1-1.south west) -- (M-1-3.south east);
     \node[rotate=90, anchor=south] at (M-4-1) {Markt-bezogene};
     \hochscale{1,2,3,2,4}
  \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for the hint with the matrix of nodes! That looks great!